# Compile Error :Method or data member not found

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm basically following this dude on this Youtube Video to create an stock in/out button for my warehouse project. However, his example differs from mine because he is using table to validate the source properties whereas I use Query to validate the source.
However, by the time I apply for this code toward my button form. The system initiates an error telling me that Method or Data member not found
What cause this problem and how do i resolve it ?

Here is the code

```
     Private Sub Command16_Click()
        Dim db As DAO.Database
       Dim rst As DAO.Database
       Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select dbo_PRODUCT.QUANTITY from DonHang where IDDH=" & Me.IDDH)
With rst
    .Edit(By the time i press debug,this line filter for some reason)
    !dbo_PRODUCT_QUANTITY = !dbo_PRODUCT.QUANTITY - Nz(Me.QuantityBox, 0)
    .Update
 
End With
Me.dbo2.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Storax the .Edit line .I click on debug and somehow it seems to be focusing on this particular line

Comment: Try to replace `Dim rst As DAO.Database` with `Dim rst As DAO.recordset` (untested)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because of your declarations - you are saying that `rst` is of a `Database` type. Try:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be dot, not underscore:

```
!dbo_PRODUCT.QUANTITY = !dbo_PRODUCT.QUANTITY - Nz(Me.QuantityBox, 0)
```

Comment: Regard of the typo. It remains the same error with the hint of .Edit Line

Comment: Applecore got it.